# Get request for txt file doesn't work on local host , but works on google colab

Tags: python, http, get

I'm trying to download the txt/csv file from the exchange.
I have identified this url to contain the info.
The code works on google colab but doesnt work on local Jupiter notebook.
The cell just keeps running without results if not interrupted and returns interruption.
**The site limits the number of tries**.

```
import requests 
import pandas as pd
import io
url = 'http://www.cffex.com.cn/quote_IO.txt'

data = requests.get(url)
CSI300_option = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.content.decode('utf-8')))
CSI300_option
```

The following is the HTTP request I have from the dev tools.

```
GET /quote_IO.txt HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Host: www.cffex.com.cn
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to be able to specify a timeout on the HTTP GET.

This is the minimal code that I use to achieve success:-

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import io

URL = 'http://www.cffex.com.cn/quote_IO.txt'

with requests.Session() as session:
    response = session.get(URL, timeout=5)
    response.raise_for_status()
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the original code worked as well after switching wifi. I believe it is the rate limiting function of the site is causing the trouble.